# open shadowbox on html form submit?

Tags: php, jquery, html, authentication, hyperlink

can some one please help me, i am using a jquery lightbox called shadowbox. Basically if a user clicks on links on my site these open in a jquery window using the following code:

```
<a href="page.php" rel="shadowbox;height=300;width=500">link</a>
```

but now i am trying to get a login html form on submit to open in a jquery window by coding it like this:

```
<form action="login.php"  rel="shadowbox;height=300;width=500" method="post" class="loginform">

    Email
    <input type="text" name="email" maxlength="30" />

    Password
    <input type="password" name="password" maxlength="30" />

    <input type="image" src="../PTB1/assets/img/icons/loginarrow1.png" name="submit" class="loginbutton" value="Login" />

</form>
```

At the moment though its not opening in a jquery window and is just using the same pre-existing page when login in. Can someone please show me what i could do. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need do request your form in the js, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showBox(){
Shadowbox.open({
content: '<form action="login.php" method="post" id="login-form" class="loginform">Email<input id="email" type="text" name="email" maxlength="30" />Password<input type="password" id="pass" name="password" maxlength="30" /><input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="loginbutton" value="Login" /></form>',
player: "html",
title: "Login-form",
height: 300,
width: 500
});
}
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="showBox()">Login-form</a>
```

Use input or button with type="submit", and in the login-form you need use ajax-techology for check request data, like this:

$(document).ready(function(){

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
    $('#login-form').submit(function(){ return false;});
     $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'url for check data',
        data: {'email':$('#email').val(),'pass':$('#pass').val()},
        success: function(result){
          if(result == 'ok') $('#login-form').submit();
          else alert('error!');
}
      });
  });
});
```